# Can't open a .obj file

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I downloaded a zip file online which contains codes for Abaqus. The UMAT code, named CMSG.obj . When I open it, this is what it says

There is no application installed for “TGIF document” files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

After clicking yes, it searches and says

TGIF document not supported.

My question is: What is a TGIF document and how is it rellated to .obj files. Also is there any software I can use to open this file. My guess is that it contains a 3D images.

Comment: Can I see a link to that zip file and if possible I would like to get the `.obj` file also!

Answer (score 0):

Tgif is a graphics program used for graphics, perhaps its incorporated into `abaqus`.

Also [source](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Epsgendb/doc/tgif/TGIF.Intro.html):

> TGIF is a versatile but simple drawing program. As compared to Adobe Photoshop or PowerPoint, TGIF focuses on letting you do simple things quickly and easily, rather than making everything a sophisticated and complex process. After using TGIF routinely for many years, I have found that probably 95% of the time, the more elaborate programs were really overkill for the job I wanted to do.
>
> The progress of the export will be shown in the Message window. The name of the output file will consist of the base name of the current file (ie. minus the .obj extension) with an extension indicating the format. For example, if the TGIF file was named 'schema_template.obj', and you export as a GIF image, the ouput filename would be 'schema_template.gif'.  You can export to EPS (.eps), PostScript (.ps), X-bitmap (.xbm), EPSI (.epsi), GIF (.gif), and HTML fomats. Some installations of TGIF also allow PNG (.png) and JPEG formats (.jpg).

Tgif files are stored in the `.obj` format before being changed to other graphics format say `.gif`, `png`, `jpg`, `ps`, `gif` etc.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tgif_(program)) and [here](http://bourbon.usc.edu/tgif/download.html) for tgif.

To install do:

```
sudo apt-get install tgif

#or

sudo apt install tgif
```

Comment: Hi George, thanks for the information. I installed tgif but still my my .obj file doesn't want to open. It still says TGIF document not supported.

Comment: Please restart your system and try again...

Comment: Restarted it numerous times, still doesn't open

Comment: Please give me the link to the `zip` file you download let me try to reproduce the issue...

Comment: Its in this page http://www.empaneda.com/codes/    under ABAQUS UMAT SUBROUTINE FOR CMSG PLASTICITY

Comment: please let me also have the `.obj` file your trying to open! The link if I am correct says you have to have metlab installed ?

Comment: I believe the process is `install matlab and abaqus` then install the `tool` from your link to have it work. Was this how you installed it?

Answer (score 0):

x-tgif isn't the only file format for .obj files, even though an X-based shell will likely identify all objects as x-tgif. I believe you're looking for something to decode a program obj file, not a graphics file. This file likly doesn't contain program source, just has enough to generate program binaries. If you look at the file, a program obj file will begin with some form of target descriptor. If you see "ELF" there, it's code, not graphics. It's intended to be fed into a linker, and doesn't guarantee source (if it was compiled to include source, you may luck out and be able to pull up the source in a debugger if you can reproduce the development setup, but that goes beyond the scope of this question as it may require other files, etc.).